# Print Multivalued Map and format output using Stream API

Tags: java, dictionary, java-stream

Here is the Map(String, List(String)), List contains two values with following pattern: xxxx_yyy, zzz. The length of strings is varied for each key.

The thing is that I need to split first value of the List into two, print them and then print the second one. Then, I need to apply certain formatting, so the output should look like this:

xxxx|yyy| zzz

xxx |yy | zzz

Indent from last symbol in the string to "|" symbol should be fixed and equals the length of longest string in the List.

Is it possible to implement it in one line using Stream API?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done using one in one line using Stream API but in that case, you will have to write some custom class/es which will hold data from the stream intermediate operations. These custom class(or Pair) will hold max and min for the length of the split strings `xxxx_yyy`. This info will be used in terminal operation for printing strings in format.

Below code provides the same result but not in one line stream. First, it finds the length of strings then format the output

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class MultiValuedMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

        map.put("key1", new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("xxxx_yyy", "zzz")));
        map.put("key2", new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("xxxx_yyyy", "zzz")));
        map.put("key3", new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("xxxxx_yyy", "zzz")));
        map.put("key4", new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("xxxx_yy", "zzz")));
        map.put("key5", new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("xxxxxxx_yyy", "zzz")));

        int xLength = map.entrySet().stream().map(stringListEntry -> stringListEntry.getValue().get(0).split("_")[0])
                .mapToInt(String::length).max().orElse(0);
        int yLength = map.entrySet().stream().map(stringListEntry -> stringListEntry.getValue().get(0).split("_")[1])
                .mapToInt(String::length).max().orElse(0);
        map.forEach((key, value) -> {
            String[] arr = value.get(0).split("_");
            System.out.println(arr[0] + getEmptyString(xLength - arr[0].length()) + "|"
                    + arr[1] + getEmptyString(yLength - arr[1].length()) + "|" + value.get(1));
        });
    }

    private static String getEmptyString(int length) {
        StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder();
        while(length > 0) {
            ret.append(" ");
            length--;
        }
        return ret.toString();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
xxxx   |yyy |zzz
xxxx   |yyyy|zzz
xxxxxxx|yyy |zzz
xxxxx  |yyy |zzz
xxxx   |yy  |zzz
```

Answer (score 0):

First, as I understand you don't operate on map but only with lists that are in this map.
So lists can be extracted and strings can be splitted in first operation.

```java
List<List<String>> listOfListOfStrings = map.values().stream()
    .map(v -> Arrays.asList(v.get(0).split("_")[0], v.get(0).split("_")[1], v.get(1)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

After that max (fixed) length of each column can be computed.

```java
List<Integer> maxSpacesForEachColumn = listOfListOfStrings.stream()
    .map(a ->
        a.stream().map(String::length).collect(Collectors.toList())
    )
    .reduce(Collections.nCopies(listOfListOfStrings.get(0).size(), 0), (a, v) ->
        IntStream
            .range(0, a.size())
            .mapToObj(i -> a.get(i) > v.get(i) ? a.get(i) : v.get(i))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
    );
```

And finally those two collection can be combined together. For right pad `String.format` is used:

```java
listOfListOfStrings.stream()
    .map(v -> IntStream
        .range(0, maxSpacesForEachColumn.size())
        .mapToObj(i ->
            String.format("%1$-" + maxSpacesForEachColumn.get(i) + "s", v.get(i)))
        .collect(Collectors.joining("|")))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Obviously it is not one line but trying to do so would make the code unreadable. This solution can also be quite unreadable. But creating `listOfListOfStrings` is only specific for your domain, after that the rest of code is generic.